# What's a good key vault system that can be attached to the car while gone surfing?

Tags: security

I'm looking for something like a vault with a number lock that can be attached to the car and where I can store the car key in it, while I'm gone surfing.

Eventually something similar like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000I66JEM) but I don't have a tow hitch. So maybe even something which I can chain around the wheels or another strong part of the car would work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

How about [something like the Lock Box KeyGuard Pro](http://www.sanzospecialties.com/index.cfm?action=cat.prodInfo&productID=770&categoryID=59)?